# Passing parameters from Jquery popup to aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is the popup content

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function () {
        var name = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if (username == "" || password == "") {
            alert("Username or Password was Wrong");
        } else {
            $("#logindiv").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
```

I want to capture the username and password back to the page for database checking. How will i sent back the values to the aspx page, specifically aspx.cs page??

Comment: Maybe try google ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with hidden field in aspx page. Then form aspx page, you can get values in aspx.cs.

```
 $("#loginbtn").click(function () {
    var name = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    if (username == "" || password == "") {
        alert("Username or Password was Wrong");
    } else {
        $("#logindiv").css("display", "none");
        $("#<%= hiddenUSerName.ClientID %>").val( name );
        $("#<%= hiddenPassworde.ClientID %>").val( password );
    }
});
```